# Read-write lock implementation for Ruby, new version

Tags: ruby, multithreading, locking

I recently discovered that there is no free read-write lock implementation for Ruby available on the Internet, so I built one myself. The intention is to keep it posted on GitHub indefinitely for the Ruby community at large to use.

The code is at https://github.com/alexdowad/showcase/blob/master/ruby-threads/read_write_lock.rb. For convenience, it is also repeated below. (There is another version which goes further to avoid reader starvation; it is currently at https://github.com/alexdowad/showcase/blob/fair-to-readers/ruby-threads/read_write_lock.rb.)

Alex Kliuchnikau very kindly reviewed the first version and found a serious bug. To fix that bug, I had to rethink the implementation and make some major changes. I am hoping someone can review the new version, first for correctness, and then for any ways to increase performance. Also, if you have a multi-core processor, please try running the file (it has a built-in test script). Problems which don't show up on my single-core machine may show up much more easily with multiple cores.

```
# Ruby read-write lock implementation
# Allows any number of concurrent readers, but only one concurrent writer
# (And if the "write" lock is taken, any readers who come along will have to wait)

# If readers are already active when a writer comes along, the writer will wait for
#   all the readers to finish before going ahead
# But any additional readers who come when the writer is already waiting, will also
#   wait (so writers are not starved)

# Written by Alex Dowad
# Bug fixes contributed by Alex Kliuchnikau
# Thanks to Doug Lea for java.util.concurrent.ReentrantReadWriteLock (used for inspiration)

# Usage:
# lock = ReadWriteLock.new
# lock.with_read_lock  { data.retrieve }
# lock.with_write_lock { data.modify! }

# Implementation notes: 
# A goal is to make the uncontended path for both readers/writers lock-free
# Only if there is reader-writer or writer-writer contention, should locks be used
# Internal state is represented by a single integer ("counter"), and updated 
#  using atomic compare-and-swap operations
# When the counter is 0, the lock is free
# Each reader increments the counter by 1 when acquiring a read lock
#   (and decrements by 1 when releasing the read lock)
# The counter is increased by (1 << 15) for each writer waiting to acquire the
#   write lock, and by (1 << 30) if the write lock is taken

require 'atomic'
require 'thread'

class ReadWriteLock
  def initialize
    @counter      = Atomic.new(0)         # single integer which represents lock state
    @reader_q     = ConditionVariable.new # queue for waiting readers
    @reader_mutex = Mutex.new             # to protect reader queue
    @writer_q     = ConditionVariable.new # queue for waiting writers
    @writer_mutex = Mutex.new             # to protect writer queue
  end

  WAITING_WRITER  = 1 << 15
  RUNNING_WRITER  = 1 << 30
  MAX_READERS     = WAITING_WRITER - 1
  MAX_WRITERS     = RUNNING_WRITER - MAX_READERS - 1

  def with_read_lock
    acquire_read_lock
    yield
    release_read_lock
  end

  def with_write_lock
    acquire_write_lock
    yield
    release_write_lock
  end

  def acquire_read_lock
    while(true)
      c = @counter.value
      raise "Too many reader threads!" if (c & MAX_READERS) == MAX_READERS

      # If a writer is running OR waiting, we need to wait
      if c >= WAITING_WRITER
        # But it is possible that the writer could finish and decrement @counter right here...
        @reader_mutex.synchronize do 
          # So check again inside the synchronized section
          @reader_q.wait(@reader_mutex) if @counter.value >= WAITING_WRITER
        end
      else
        break if @counter.compare_and_swap(c,c+1)
      end
    end    
  end

  def release_read_lock
    while(true)
      c = @counter.value
      if @counter.compare_and_swap(c,c-1)
        # If one or more writers were waiting, and we were the last reader, wake a writer up
        if c >= WAITING_WRITER && (c & MAX_READERS) == 1
          @writer_mutex.synchronize { @writer_q.signal }
        end
        break
      end
    end
  end

  def acquire_write_lock
    while(true)
      c = @counter.value
      raise "Too many writers!" if (c & MAX_WRITERS) == MAX_WRITERS

      if c == 0 # no readers OR writers running
        # if we successfully swap the RUNNING_WRITER bit on, then we can go ahead
        break if @counter.compare_and_swap(0,RUNNING_WRITER)
      elsif @counter.compare_and_swap(c,c+WAITING_WRITER)
        while(true)
          # Now we have successfully incremented, so no more readers will be able to increment
          #   (they will wait instead)
          # However, readers OR writers could decrement right here, OR another writer could increment
          @writer_mutex.synchronize do
            # So we have to do another check inside the synchronized section
            # If a writer OR reader is running, then go to sleep
            c = @counter.value
            @writer_q.wait(@writer_mutex) if (c >= RUNNING_WRITER) || ((c & MAX_READERS) > 0)
          end

          # We just came out of a wait
          # If we successfully turn the RUNNING_WRITER bit on with an atomic swap,
          # Then we are OK to stop waiting and go ahead
          # Otherwise go back and wait again
          c = @counter.value
          break if (c < RUNNING_WRITER) && @counter.compare_and_swap(c,c+RUNNING_WRITER-WAITING_WRITER)
        end
        break
      end
    end
  end

  def release_write_lock
    while(true)
      c = @counter.value
      if @counter.compare_and_swap(c,c-RUNNING_WRITER)
        if (c & MAX_WRITERS) > 0 # if any writers are waiting...
          @writer_mutex.synchronize { @writer_q.signal }
        else
          @reader_mutex.synchronize { @reader_q.broadcast }
        end
        break
      end
    end
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $0

# for performance comparison with ReadWriteLock
class SimpleMutex
  def initialize; @mutex = Mutex.new; end
  def with_read_lock
    @mutex.synchronize { yield }
  end
  alias :with_write_lock :with_read_lock
end

# for seeing whether my correctness test is doing anything...
# and for seeing how great the overhead of the test is
# (apart from the cost of locking)
class FreeAndEasy
  def with_read_lock
    yield # thread safety is for the birds... I prefer to live dangerously
  end
  alias :with_write_lock :with_read_lock
end

require 'benchmark'

TOTAL_THREADS = 40 # set this number as high as practicable!

def test(lock)
  puts "READ INTENSIVE (80% read, 20% write):"
  single_test(lock, (TOTAL_THREADS * 0.8).floor, (TOTAL_THREADS * 0.2).floor)
  puts "WRITE INTENSIVE (80% write, 20% read):"
  single_test(lock, (TOTAL_THREADS * 0.2).floor, (TOTAL_THREADS * 0.8).floor)
  puts "BALANCED (50% read, 50% write):"
  single_test(lock, (TOTAL_THREADS * 0.5).floor, (TOTAL_THREADS * 0.5).floor)
end

def single_test(lock, n_readers, n_writers, reader_iterations=50, writer_iterations=50, reader_sleep=0.001, writer_sleep=0.001)
  puts "Testing #{lock.class} with #{n_readers} readers and #{n_writers} writers. Readers iterate #{reader_iterations} times, sleeping #{reader_sleep}s each time, writers iterate #{writer_iterations} times, sleeping #{writer_sleep}s each time"
  mutex = Mutex.new
  bad   = false
  data  = 0

  result = Benchmark.measure do
    readers = n_readers.times.collect do
                Thread.new do
                  reader_iterations.times do
                    lock.with_read_lock do
                      mutex.synchronize { bad = true } if (data % 2) != 0
                      sleep(reader_sleep)
                      mutex.synchronize { bad = true } if (data % 2) != 0
                    end
                  end
                end
              end
    writers = n_writers.times.collect do
                Thread.new do
                  writer_iterations.times do
                    lock.with_write_lock do
                      # invariant: other threads should NEVER see "data" as an odd number
                      value = (data += 1)
                      # if a reader runs right now, this invariant will be violated
                      sleep(writer_sleep)
                      # this looks like a strange way to increment twice;
                      # it's designed so that if 2 writers run at the same time, at least
                      #   one increment will be lost, and we can detect that at the end
                      data  = value+1 
                    end
                  end
                end
              end

    readers.each { |t| t.join }
    writers.each { |t| t.join }
    puts "BAD!!! Readers+writers overlapped!" if mutex.synchronize { bad }
    puts "BAD!!! Writers overlapped!" if data != (n_writers * writer_iterations * 2)
  end
  puts result
end

test(ReadWriteLock.new)
test(SimpleMutex.new)
test(FreeAndEasy.new)
end
```

Comment: And if someone were to test it on JRuby on an 864 core Azul Vega system, I'm sure Alex wouldn't complain, either :-)

Comment: Actually, anybody at all who can just run the test script and post the results is highly appreciated. I would feel irresponsible putting this up on the web for people to use, unless it has been tested on a variety of systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered to join reader and writer queues into a single writer-waiting queue? This may make the code easier to synchronize and also solve the issue with readers starvation when constant writes are performed, something like this:

1. if write lock is taken or queue is not empty, new operation (read or write) goes into queue
2. if no write lock is taken and queue is empty, new read operation is performed. New write operation goes into queue and waits for read operations to end
3. when write lock released, run next operation from the queue. If this is read operation, try run next operations until encounter write operation/queue is empty. If write operation is encounered, wait for reads (see item 2)

---

I believe you should encapsulate operations on the counter into separate, say `ReadWriteCounter`, abstraction. It will hold `Atomic` `@counter` instance internally and will perform check and operations through methods like `new_writer`, `writer_running?` etc. This should improve code readability.

---

I ran the code at Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5400 @ 2.70GHz machine:

MRI Ruby 1.9.2-p290:

```
READ INTENSIVE (80% read, 20% write):
Testing ReadWriteLock with 32 readers and 8 writers. Readers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time, writers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time
  0.030000   0.030000   0.060000 (  0.499945)
WRITE INTENSIVE (80% write, 20% read):
Testing ReadWriteLock with 8 readers and 32 writers. Readers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time, writers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time
  0.030000   0.010000   0.040000 (  1.761913)
BALANCED (50% read, 50% write):
Testing ReadWriteLock with 20 readers and 20 writers. Readers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time, writers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time
  0.030000   0.010000   0.040000 (  1.121450)
READ INTENSIVE (80% read, 20% write):
Testing SimpleMutex with 32 readers and 8 writers. Readers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time, writers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time
  0.010000   0.020000   0.030000 (  2.125943)
WRITE INTENSIVE (80% write, 20% read):
Testing SimpleMutex with 8 readers and 32 writers. Readers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time, writers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time
  0.010000   0.010000   0.020000 (  2.114639)
BALANCED (50% read, 50% write):
Testing SimpleMutex with 20 readers and 20 writers. Readers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time, writers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time
  0.010000   0.010000   0.020000 (  2.114838)
READ INTENSIVE (80% read, 20% write):
Testing FreeAndEasy with 32 readers and 8 writers. Readers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time, writers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time
BAD!!! Readers+writers overlapped!
BAD!!! Writers overlapped!
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.058086)
WRITE INTENSIVE (80% write, 20% read):
Testing FreeAndEasy with 8 readers and 32 writers. Readers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time, writers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time
BAD!!! Readers+writers overlapped!
BAD!!! Writers overlapped!
  0.010000   0.010000   0.020000 (  0.060335)
BALANCED (50% read, 50% write):
Testing FreeAndEasy with 20 readers and 20 writers. Readers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time, writers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time
BAD!!! Readers+writers overlapped!
BAD!!! Writers overlapped!
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.057053)
```

Jruby 1.6.5.1:

```
READ INTENSIVE (80% read, 20% write):
Testing ReadWriteLock with 32 readers and 8 writers. Readers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time, writers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time
  0.875000   0.000000   0.875000 (  0.875000)
WRITE INTENSIVE (80% write, 20% read):
Testing ReadWriteLock with 8 readers and 32 writers. Readers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time, writers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time
  1.880000   0.000000   1.880000 (  1.880000)
BALANCED (50% read, 50% write):
Testing ReadWriteLock with 20 readers and 20 writers. Readers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time, writers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time
  1.201000   0.000000   1.201000 (  1.201000)
READ INTENSIVE (80% read, 20% write):
Testing SimpleMutex with 32 readers and 8 writers. Readers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time, writers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time
  2.196000   0.000000   2.196000 (  2.196000)
WRITE INTENSIVE (80% write, 20% read):
Testing SimpleMutex with 8 readers and 32 writers. Readers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time, writers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time
  2.219000   0.000000   2.219000 (  2.219000)
BALANCED (50% read, 50% write):
Testing SimpleMutex with 20 readers and 20 writers. Readers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time, writers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time
  2.229000   0.000000   2.229000 (  2.229000)
READ INTENSIVE (80% read, 20% write):
Testing FreeAndEasy with 32 readers and 8 writers. Readers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time, writers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time
BAD!!! Readers+writers overlapped!
BAD!!! Writers overlapped!
  0.074000   0.000000   0.074000 (  0.074000)
WRITE INTENSIVE (80% write, 20% read):
Testing FreeAndEasy with 8 readers and 32 writers. Readers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time, writers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time
BAD!!! Readers+writers overlapped!
BAD!!! Writers overlapped!
  0.060000   0.000000   0.060000 (  0.060000)
BALANCED (50% read, 50% write):
Testing FreeAndEasy with 20 readers and 20 writers. Readers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time, writers iterate 50 times, sleeping 0.001s each time
BAD!!! Readers+writers overlapped!
BAD!!! Writers overlapped!
  0.105000   0.000000   0.105000 (  0.104000)
```

Comment: Alex, encapsulating operations on the counter is a great idea. I'm not sure if I should use a separate `ReadWriteCounter` class, or just some `private` methods on the `ReadWriteLock`. I think `private` methods may actually be enough. I really like the idea of using only 1 queue, primarily because it would reduce the memory footprint of each `ReadWriteLock` and make it more feasible to use very large numbers of them. (Have you seen the `ConcurrentHash` which I am working on? It's in my GitHub repo. I'm concerned about the memory used by `ReadWriteLock`s for that one.)

Comment: I originally decided to use 2 queues because then I can release *all* readers with `@read_q.broadcast`. Since any number of readers can run concurrently, if you release one, it's best to release them all. But the scheme you described is workable and has definite advantages too. I think I should try another implementation using the scheme you described, and compare with the current implementation...

Comment: I tried a new implementation with only a single queue, and refactored for readability at the same time. It looks much nicer than before, but performance is terrible. I haven't done any testing to figure out why yet. It's the new 'alexs-ideas' branch on my GitHub repo.

Comment: thanks for your input! I think I'm going to stick with 2 queues, but factoring out the operations on the counter is a great idea. BTW, I have a bounty which is expiring tomorrow, if you want it, please comment on this question: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/9583/concurrent-stack-implementations-in-ruby-relative-performance-of-mutexes-cas